# How to write this if-condition for real?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

How could I write this in real code?

```
if (!UIImageView with origin.x > 50.0) {
    //Exlcude the imageview from whatever happens in this statement.
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (imageView.frame.origin.x <= 50.0) {

    // The code in this block won't bother the image views 
    // with 'x > 50.0' anymore
}
```

Comment: I had been doing this, but it wasn't working right, so I figured I might be doing something wrong. I realized it was just my other logic contained in the if statement that was making it not work. It was late, I feel dumb. ;-)